# fade background color jquery a:hover

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, fade

This function work good. But How i get this in my Navigation. To  A:hover 
i wan t change background with fade when mouse hover a link?I have try this with css but it don´t work in the Internet explorer!

```
-----------------------
.boxes {
 background:#fff;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
 position:relative;
 width:510px;
}

-----------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boxes").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800);
            },function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 800);
            });
 });

</script>
----------------------------
   <div class="boxes">
    <div class="info">
    <h3>test</a> </h3>
    </div> </div>
     -------------------------
```

---

Navigation

```
<div id="mitte">
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the parent > child selector :

```
 $(".nav > a").hover(function() { 
            $('.nav').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800); 
            },function() { 
            $('.nav').stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 800); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For your navigation:

```
$("#mitte ul li a").hover(function() ...);
```

If you have to use this ALSO in boxes, just define:

```
$("#mitte ul li a").add(".boxes").hover(function() ...);
```